# Android memory leaks

Tags: android, memory

[Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Now I have a context leak in my project and on the link it pretty much explains everything that could cause it.

To be honest I tried to remove as much as possible that has context variables but I am having a problem with my Grid View and my base adapter and I really need help I have been pounding my head over this. Sometimes it elude me that it got garbage collected then shows itself like a ninja on the other classes.

My question: "What would you guys suggest that I should change?" and "What should I watch out for?"

Here is what I did:
1. Created a Hash map for my drawable images
2. Created a Base Adapter for the gridview
3. My code for the loadCover class

private static Map ImageLocator = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap());

```
private class BaseA extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public BaseA(Context context){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row = convertView;
        viewHolder vh = new viewHolder();

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_row_view, null);       
        vh.authors = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.book_Author);
        vh.image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        vh.date = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.Date);
        vh.Titles = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.Book_Title);
        vh.fileName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FileLocation);

        try{
            String temp = File_Name.get(position);
            vh.fileName.setText(temp);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Book_Information bi;
        bi = new Book_Information();
        bi = dbh.getData(File_Name.get(position));
        //Gets the right book information for all the items
        new LoadCover(vh.image, bi).run();
        if(bi.getBook_Author() != null || bi.getBook_Date() !=null || bi.getBook_Description() != null ||
                bi.getBook_Title() != null){

            vh.authors.setText(bi.getBook_Author());
            vh.date.setText(bi.getBook_Date());
            vh.Titles.setText(bi.getBook_Title());
        }                   
        return row;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return File_Name.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

}



private class LoadCover implements Runnable{
    ImageView image; Book_Information bi;

    public LoadCover(ImageView image, Book_Information bi){
        this.image = image;
        this.bi = bi;
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Drawable draw = ImageLocator.get(bi.getBook_File_Name());

        if(draw!=null){
            image.setImageDrawable(draw);
        }else{
            new UpdateImages(image, bi).run();
        }
        draw = null;
    }


}

private class UpdateImages implements Runnable{
    ImageView image;
    Book_Information book_info;

    public UpdateImages(ImageView imageView,  Book_Information bookInfo){
        this.image = imageView;
        this.book_info = bookInfo;
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            Bitmap bm = getBitmap(book_info);
            FastBitmapDrawable fbd = new FastBitmapDrawable(bm);
            image.setImageDrawable(fbd);
            ImageLocator.put(book_info.getBook_File_Name(), fbd);
            bm = null;
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            ImageLocator.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only glanced, but passing the ImageView into the LoadCover could be causing issues when you keep hold of it after an Activity has been destroyed you'll still have your Activity in memory

Comment: Should I turn it into a method? So that it gets overwritten every time on scroll?

Comment: You know your only implementing Runnable, that doesn't actually mean it runs on it's own ThreaD?

Comment: I think you need to go read up on some Java fundamentals before taking on any more Android specific problems. Your code is just .. nasty :-)

Comment: So what Java fundamentals should I read up on? Since I am not certain of your criticism here. Literally just bashing without any information rather than it looks ugly.

Comment: I'm looking at your code now. Variables declarations, class nesting, Why extend Thread or implement Runnable.

Comment: I've just noticed your using a databasehelper in the middle of getView you shouldn't do this, pass in whatever it is retrieving

Comment: The use of the databasehelper was to get the byte[] image object where it gets it from the row of the file name. If I placed it inside a constructor and created a list from it. I believed it would store all those bytes in memory causing memory issues on the scroll events

Comment: The true answer and the cause of all this was because I didn't set layoutinflater's root to false which got rooted to activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked at your code and refactored it into a more manageable manner, it has pointed out a few things.

Your doing some type of image loading in your getView method, this takes too long and should be done in an ASyncTask, or a handler with some type of callback.

You then store these bitmaps in a static map that will stay in memory for the lifetime of your app, this is baaad and keeps references to your context when you create the bitmaps. I can see your using it as a kind of image cache for when they are loaded, maybe think of a different way if this is causing you out of memory errors.

Here is your code, refactored:

```
/**
 * @author paul.blundell
 *         May 15, 2012
 */
public class MyAct extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>(); // Whatever filenames you get
        List<BookInformation> list = dbh.getData(fileNames); // However you get your data from the database (usually in a Service)

        BaseA base = new BaseA(inflater, list);

        // Do whatever with base
    }
 }
```

The adapter class:

```
    public class BaseA extends BaseAdapter {

        // Having a static map means it lives the entire life of your application, your drawables should take a context
        // when they are being created therefore they have a reference to your Activity, and this is not being destroyed
        public static Map<String, Drawable> imageLocator = new WeakHashMap<String, Drawable>();

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<BookInformation> books;

        public BaseA(LayoutInflater inflater, List<BookInformation> books) {
            this.inflater = inflater;
            this.books = books;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder vh = null;

            if(rowView == null){
                // Get new instance of our row view
                rowView = inflateView();
                // Hold the view in an object so it doesnt need to be re-fetched
                vh = new ViewHolder();

                vh.authors  = (TextView)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
                vh.image    = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.book_icon);
                vh.date     = (TextView)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.book_date);
                vh.titles   = (TextView)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
                vh.fileName = (TextView)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.file_location);

                // Cache the view so it can be re-accessed later
                rowView.setTag(vh);
            } else {
                vh = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }

            BookInformation book = books.get(position);
            vh.fileName.setText(book.getFileName());

            // Gets the right book information for all the items
            loadCover(vh.image, book.getFileName());

            if (book.getAuthor() != null){
                vh.authors.setText(book.getAuthor());
            }
            if(book.getDate() != null){
                vh.date.setText(book.getDate());
            }
            if(book.getTitle() != null){
                vh.titles.setText(book.getTitle());
            }

            return rowView;
        }

        private View inflateView() {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_book_row, null);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return books.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        private void loadCover(ImageView image, String filename) {
            Drawable draw = imageLocator.get(filename);

            if (draw == null) {
                draw = updateImage(filename);
            }
            imageLocator.put(filename, draw); // This is your problem keeping a reference to these drawables in a static map
            image.setImageDrawable(draw);
        }

        private Drawable updateImage(String filename) {
            Bitmap bm = getBitmap(filename);
            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
            return drawable;
        }

        private Bitmap getBitmap(String filename) {
            return null; // I don't know how you get a bitmap but you shouldn't do this in getView() , use a callback
        }

       private static class ViewHolder {
            public TextView fileName;
            public TextView titles;
            public TextView date;
            public ImageView image;
            public TextView authors;
        }
    }
```

Separate domain class bookInformation:

```
public class BookInformation {

        public String getFileName() {
            return "filename";
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return "title";
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return "date";
        }

        public String getAuthor() {
            return "author";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I should have placed it inside my base adapter for the hashmap. Thanks for the information regarding database handler.